# Fragment instance dissapear when app is in background

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have an app that contains DrawerLayout and Navigation Component.

Listener is set with NavigationItemSelectedListener instead of the setupWithNavController because I want to handle the instances of Fragment instead of recreating/replacing over and over

When I press back in **Fragment A** it leaves the app in "background mode" (That's normal) and when I return to the app and go from **FRAGMENT A TO FRAGMENT B** it destroys the **FRAGMENT A AND THE VIEWMODEL** and now I can't get the instance of that fragment doing a popBackStack().

Something I noticed is that when the app goes in the background, the **backstack of navController is cleaned**, therefore once I get back to the app the fragment where I left (**Fragment A**) will be destroyed once I navigate to another fragment and I can't get back that instance.

This is gets super difficult because I just want to handle the instances of the fragments but it just creates a new one. And the popbackStack can't find the old fragment once the APP is in background so I don't know what I can do.

If I set an action in the nav graph from Fragment_A to Fragment_B, after leaving the app and re-entering and navigating to **Fragment_B** it appears an error: ***action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB cannot be found from the current destination NavGraph***

I just have a custom onBackPressed in **Fragment A** to leave the app using.

```
fun defaultOnBackPressed() {
    if (findNavController().popBackStack().not()) {
        requireActivity().moveTaskToBack(true)
    } else {
        findNavController().popBackStack()
    }
}
```

What should I do?

It's been 2 days since I've been trying to solve this, but I can't get to solve something so complex that imo should be easy. I have tried a lot of solutions. Feel free to request any code.

Comment: can you provide more code and tell us where do you have the problem in your code

Comment: It's been solved, thank you for asking :) @mmdrezabaqalpour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change your **if statement**. you are **calling** popBackstack() function while you are checking if statement and it pops. you can replace your statement as either:

```
fun defaultOnBackPressed() {
    if (requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.fragments.size() == 1) {
        requireActivity().moveTaskToBack(true)
    } else {
        findNavController().popBackStack()
    }
}
```

Or

```
fun defaultOnBackPressed() {
    if (requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount == 1) {
        requireActivity().moveTaskToBack(true)
    } else {
        findNavController().popBackStack()
    }
}
```